# Hide Nav-bar in Login page in .net, fails when clicking back button in browser

Tags: .net, logging, navbar

I'm trying to hide the nav-bar from Login page, which works with the following code:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{                   

    <div class="top navbar-fixed-top navbar-banner">             
    </div>     
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-blue-background">     
        <div class="container">                      
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="padding-top: 23px;">      

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">      
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("HOME", "Index", "Home")</li>     
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("SUPPLIERS", "Suppliers", "Home")</li>      
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("ECONTENT", "EContent", "Home")</li>      
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("PRODUCT INFO", "ProductInfo", "Home")</li>      
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("ADMINISTRATION", "Administration", "Home")</li>      
                </ul>      
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")     
            </div>      
        </div>     
    </div>     
    <div class="container body-content">     
        @RenderBody()     
        <hr />     
        <footer >      
                <center><p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Powered by <b>Myself</b></p></center>             
             </footer>             
              </div>            
}               
  else{            
    <div class="container body-content">     
        @RenderBody()          
    </div>          
}
```

However, the problem is when I click the back button in the browser, since "it is still logged in", will show the login page with the nav bar..

any suggestions? I'm using .net 4.6 and MVC pattern///

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure if this is the best way to handle this issue, but I just added another validation to my code:

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && (ViewBag.Title != "Login"))

of course I need to add ViewBag.Title attribute to the login page to make it work. As I mentioned before, not sure if this is the best way to do it, but at least seems to be ok